# pyunpack Archive.extractall hangs on password protected .rar file

Tags: rar

I'm writing a python script to process some old archives that include many .rar files. I can successfully extract data from them using Archive.extractall from pyunpack, but haven't been able to find much documentation. The documentation link at https://pypi.org/project/pyunpack/0.1.2/ is broken. Everything was going well until the program hung on a specific .rar file. I looked at the file with 7zip, and it said it was password protected. I have no idea what the password is, so I would like the script to simply skip it. I already have extractall in a try block, but I guess there is no exception. How can I test if the file is password protected and not try to extract it if so? Here's the relevant portion of my code.

```
import os
import rarfile
from pyunpack import Archive

for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(directoryToExtract):
        for file in files:
            if rarfile.is_rarfile(os.path.join(subdir, file)):
                print("Found rarfile " + os.path.join(subdir, file))
                try:                    
                    Archive(os.path.join(subdir, file)).extractall(os.path.join(subdir, file[0:len(file)-4]),auto_create_dir=True)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("ERROR: Couldn't unrar " + os.path.join(subdir, file))
                    print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for extracting password protected RAR files.

```
try:
   patoolib.extract_archive(rar_file, outdir=extract_dir, password="password")
except:
   continue
```